# RawSqlQuery minimizing risk of field name confusion

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to make the following code more maintainable?

```
public static DtoNumOrderedNumDone GetNumOrderedNumDone(int jobTaskId)
{
    const string selectList = "Quantity, NumDone";
    var sql =
        @$"select  convert(int,numordered) as Quantity , convert(int,sum(isnull(numDone,0)))  as NumDone
            from task k left outer join taskdone d on k.jobtaskid = d.jobtaskid 
            inner join job j on k.jobid = j.jobid 
            where k.jobtaskid = {jobTaskId}
            group by k.jobtaskid, j.NumOrdered";

    var tokens = selectList.Tokenize();
    var quantityOrdinal = Array.IndexOf(tokens, "Quantity");
    var numdoneOrdinal = Array.IndexOf(tokens, "NumDone");
    var dtos = DataHelpers.RawSqlQuery(sql, x => new DtoNumOrderedNumDone()
    {
        NumDone = x.GetInt32(numdoneOrdinal),
        Quantity = x.GetInt32(quantityOrdinal)
    }
    );
    var dto = dtos.FirstOrDefault();
    return dto;
}
```

I aren't worried about sql injection because jobTaskId is an int, however I am worried that the code is vulnerable to being altered later and the field order being made incorrect.

[Update]

The helper code is

```
public static class DataHelpers
{
    public static List<T> RawSqlQuery<T>(string query, Func<DbDataReader, T> map, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            using var context = MakeDbContext();
            return RunQuery(context, query, map, parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
    public static List<T> RunQuery<T>(MyDbContext context, string query, Func<DbDataReader, T> map,
        params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            var cn = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
            var oldState = cn.State;
            if (cn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed)) cn.Open();
            using var command = cn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            foreach (var param in parameters) command.Parameters.Add(param);
            if (cn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed)) cn.Open();
            var entities = new List<T>();
            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (result.Read())
                {
                    var r = map(result);
                    entities.Add(r);
                }
            }

            if (oldState.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed) && cn.State == ConnectionState.Open) cn.Close();
            return entities;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"RunQuery inner: {e.InnerException}, ex:{e} \r\n {query}");
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

    }
```

[Update]

Exploring ISR5's answer I get

[image: this error message]

Comment: You could build the query through IQuerable, or create a view and add it as an entity. Then use the entity instead of raw sql.

Comment: Although it is kind of too little to have entitiy status really.

Comment: are task and job tables are entities ?

Comment: they do happen to be but I am interested in using sql here because there will be similar scenarios where they are not.

Comment: If you want to use raw sql, then you could use store procedure or SQL TVF function. Then, call it back from the code.

Comment: @iSR5 what benefit would TVF be?

Comment: `TVF` would give you a parametrized query, and the query would be stored in the DBMS instead of code. so you call it like `SELECT Quantity, NumDone FROM dbo.GetNumOrderedNumDone(@jobTaskId)`

Comment: How does that help? Wouldn't I still need to use x.GetInt32(ordinal)?

Comment: Can you please share with us the `DataHelpers.RawSqlQuery` method's code?

Comment: @PeterCsala I updated the question to include it.

Comment: @Kirsten Thanks for sharing that, now I see that `x` is a `DbDataReader`. Why do you need the `selectList`? Why don't you use `x.GetFieldValue<int>(x.GetOrdinal("Quantity"))` inside your `map` function?

Comment: @PeterCsala I thought a string look up in the loop would take longer

Comment: @Kirsten Well if your `RunQuery` would receive a `Func<DbDataReader, List<T>>` mapper then you can retrieve the indices only once and use it multiple times. The drawback is that your `RawSqlQuery` usage would become a bit more complex and tedious. But at least you could avoid to have closure like you have now.

Comment: @Kirsten Shall I leave a post where I detail the proposed solution?

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `GetNumOrderedNumDone` method then you can see that you have repeated the column names three times. It can cause problem when you need to rename one of them, because you have to update it in multiple places.

There are several ways to fix this:

- Define `const`s for column names
- Define a custom attribute, decorate the DTO's properties and use reflection to retrieve column names
- etc.

I will show you the first approach, but in order to get there we need to do some refactoring.

#### 1st iteration

As discussed in the comments section if you change the `RunQuery` to receive a `Func<DbDataReader, List<T>>` parameter then the column indexes can be cached (on the `map` function implementation side) and be reused

```
public static List<T> RunQuery<T>(MyDbContext context, string query, 
    Func<DbDataReader, List<T>> map,
    params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    try
    {
        //...
        if (cn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed)) cn.Open();

        using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var entities = reader.HasRows ? map(reader) : new List<T>();
                    
        if (oldState.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed) && cn.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
            cn.Close();
        return entities;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

- Since some responsibility has been shifted to the consumer of your helper method that's why the `DbDataReader` usage became cleaner
- I've added here the `HasRows` check to avoid calling `map` function unnecessary if there is nothing to map

Then your `GetNumOrderedNumDone` can be rewritten like this:

```
public static DtoNumOrderedNumDone GetNumOrderedNumDone(int jobTaskId)
{
    const string QuantityColumnName = "Quantity", NumDoneColumnName = "NumDone";
    var sql =
        @$"select  convert(int,numordered) as {QuantityColumnName} , convert(int,sum(isnull(numDone,0)))  as {NumDoneColumnName}
    from task k left outer join taskdone d on k.jobtaskid = d.jobtaskid 
    inner join job j on k.jobid = j.jobid 
    where k.jobtaskid = {jobTaskId}
    group by k.jobtaskid, j.NumOrdered";

    var dtos = DataHelpers.RawSqlQuery(sql, reader => {
        int quatityColumnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(QuantityColumnName);
        int numDoneColumnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(NumDoneColumnName);

        return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(record => new DtoNumOrderedNumDone
        {
            NumDone = record.GetInt32(quatityColumnIndex),
            Quantity = record.GetInt32(numDoneColumnIndex)
        }).ToList();
    }
    );
    var dto = dtos.FirstOrDefault();
    return dto;
}
```

- I've defined two constants that are storing the column names

  - Since you are already using string interpolation for your query it is really convenient to use these there as well
- Inside the `RawSqlQuery` first I've cached the column indexes to be able to reuse them multiple times
- The second part of the map implementation is a bit tricker

  - If you have a `DbDataReader` then you can use the `Read` method to iterate through it or you can treat it as `IEnumerable`

    - If you are unaware of this capability then I highly recommend to read these SO topics: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916885/casting-ado-net-datareader-to-idatarecord-giving-strange-result), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35996389/convert-sqldatareader-to-linq-expression/35996907)
  - So, after we have converted the `DbDataReader` to `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>` we can use Linq

#### 2nd iteration

What is the problem with the first one?

The `RunQuery` is generic enough to be used for queries which might return 0, 1 or multiple rows. In your particular case the cardinality is 0..1. So, calling the `ToList` inside the `RawSqlQuery` then calling the `FirstOrDefault` on the returned collection seems a bit overkill.

So, if you introduce an overload for the `RunQuery` (and for the `RawSqlQuery` as well) which can return 0 or 1 entity then the usage could be more streamlined.

Let's start with the `RunQuery`

```
public static T RunQuery<T>(MyDbContext context, string query,
    Func<DbDataReader, T> map,
    params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    try
    {
        //...
        if (cn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed)) cn.Open();

        using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        T entity = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Count() switch {
            1 => map(reader),
            0 => default,
            _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Query returned more than 1 rows")
        };
                    
        if (oldState.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed) && cn.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
           cn.Close();
        return entity;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

- Here I've used the `Count()` instead of `HasRows` to be able to handle each cases accordingly

  - If there is only one record then it should call the `map` function
  - If there is zero matching record then it should return `default(T)`
  - If there are more than one matching records then it should throw exception

The usage could be simplified like this

```
public static DtoNumOrderedNumDone GetNumOrderedNumDone(int jobTaskId)
{
    const string QuantityColumnName = "Quantity", NumDoneColumnName = "NumDone";
    var sql =
        @$"select  convert(int,numordered) as {QuantityColumnName} , convert(int,sum(isnull(numDone,0)))  as {NumDoneColumnName}
    from task k left outer join taskdone d on k.jobtaskid = d.jobtaskid 
    inner join job j on k.jobid = j.jobid 
    where k.jobtaskid = {jobTaskId}
    group by k.jobtaskid, j.NumOrdered";

    return DataHelpers.RawSqlQuery(sql, reader =>
        reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(record => new DtoNumOrderedNumDone
        {
            NumDone = record.GetInt32(record.GetOrdinal(QuantityColumnName)),
            Quantity = record.GetInt32(record.GetOrdinal(NumDoneColumnName))
        }).FirstOrDefault()
    );
}
```

- For the sake of brevity I've omitted the exception handling but you should do that
- Since we know that the `Select` will be called only once that's why we do not need to cache the column indices

---

**UPDATE #1**: `map(reader)` problem

I have to confess that I have rarely used `DbDataReader` in the past decade so I have forgotten that `Cast<IDataRecrod>` creates a forward-only iterator. There is no real `Reset` function which can rewind that `IEnumerable`. So, after calling the `Count` method the iteration reaches its end. That's why it can't be reiterated.

There are several workarounds for that, like:

- Issue two select statements where the 2nd is `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` and then use `NextResult` to move the iterator to next result set
- `Load` the `DataReader` into a `DataTable` and pass that around
- Use `SingleOrDefault` on the map implementation side to enforce 0..1 cardinality
- Pass `IDataRecord` to `map` instead of `DbDataReader`
- etc.

Let me show you the last two options

#### `SingleOrDefault`

```
public static T RunQuery<T>(MyDbContext context, string query, 
    Func<DbDataReader, T> map,
    params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    try
    {
        //...
        if (cn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed)) cn.Open();

        using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var entity = map(reader);
                    
        if (oldState.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed) && cn.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
           cn.Close();
        return entity;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

- The `RunQuery` is simplified since the cardinality enforcement is shifted to the `map` function

```
public static DtoNumOrderedNumDone GetNumOrderedNumDone(int jobTaskId)
{
    const string QuantityColumnName = "Quantity", NumDoneColumnName = "NumDone";
    var sql =
        @$"select  convert(int,numordered) as {QuantityColumnName} , convert(int,sum(isnull(numDone,0)))  as {NumDoneColumnName}
    from task k left outer join taskdone d on k.jobtaskid = d.jobtaskid 
    inner join job j on k.jobid = j.jobid 
    where k.jobtaskid = {jobTaskId}
    group by k.jobtaskid, j.NumOrdered";

    return DataHelpers.RawSqlQuery(sql, reader =>
       reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(record => new DtoNumOrderedNumDone
       {
           NumDone = record.GetInt32(record.GetOrdinal(QuantityColumnName)),
           Quantity = record.GetInt32(record.GetOrdinal(NumDoneColumnName))
       }).SingleOrDefault()
    );
}
```

#### `IDataRecord`

**NOTE:** I have tested this approach with sqlite, but I hope this approach works as well with MSSQL as well.

```
public static T RunQuery<T>(MyDbContext context, string query,
    Func<IDataRecord, T> map,
    params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    try
    {
        //...
        if (cn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed)) cn.Open();

        using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var rawEntities = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().ToList();
        T entity = rawEntities.Count switch
        {
            1 => map(rawEntities.First()),
            0 => default,
            _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Query returned more than 1 rows")
        };

        if (oldState.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed) && cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            cn.Close();
        return entity;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

- Here we retrieve the `IDataRecord`s into a helper variable and make the branching on its `Count` property
- Please note that here we are passing the `IDataRecord` to the map function not the `reader`

```
public static DtoNumOrderedNumDone GetNumOrderedNumDone(int jobTaskId)
{
    const string QuantityColumnName = "Quantity", NumDoneColumnName = "NumDone";
    var sql =
        @$"select  convert(int,numordered) as {QuantityColumnName} , convert(int,sum(isnull(numDone,0)))  as {NumDoneColumnName}
    from task k left outer join taskdone d on k.jobtaskid = d.jobtaskid 
    inner join job j on k.jobid = j.jobid 
    where k.jobtaskid = {jobTaskId}
    group by k.jobtaskid, j.NumOrdered";

    return DataHelpers.RawSqlQuery(sql, record => new DtoNumOrderedNumDone
    {
        NumDone = record.GetInt32(record.GetOrdinal(QuantityColumnName)),
        Quantity = record.GetInt32(record.GetOrdinal(NumDoneColumnName))
    });
}
```

---

I suggest the second approach since

- You can't enforce the `map` implementor to call `SingleOrDefault` instead of `First` or `FirstOrDefault`
- The `map` implementation is way more concise compare to the `SingleOrDefault` approach
- You are not leaking implementation detail (`DataReader`) so the `map` implementor for example can't dispose the `reader`
- Your intent is better expressed since you are passing a single record to map to an entity type

---

**UPDATE #2**: Share `RawSqlQuery` method

```
public static T RawSqlQuery<T>(string query, Func<IDataRecord, T> map, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    try
    {
        using var context = MakeDbContext();
        return RunQuery(context, query, map, parameters);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. It looks good. I am having a problem getting it to run. Will try with a fresh brain tomorrow.

Comment: @Kirsten Fingers crossed. If you experience any problem, please let me know.

Comment: DtoNumOrderedNumDone returns null, even though the SQL returns 1 record. Could it be to do with the cast to IDataRecord?

Comment: @Kirsten which version (iteration) are you testing?

Comment: The second. map(reader) is null.

Comment: @Kirsten yes, your assumption is correct. It's null since the Cast+Count iterated through the IEnumerable, so you can't read it again. It's my mistake I will fix it on Monday.

Comment: @Kirsten I've updated my post, please check it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you  Can you add RawSqlQuery ? I figured it is something like public static DtoNumOrderedNumDone RawSqlQuery(string sql, Func<IDataRecord, DtoNumOrderedNumDone> func)
    {
        using var context = MakeDbContext();
        return RunQuery<DtoNumOrderedNumDone>(context, sql, func);
    }

Comment: @Kirsten I've updated.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing the mapping manually each time, we can use Reflection to get the property name or `ColumnAttribute` name, and map the `SELECT` based on the given model.

A quick modification on `DataHelper` (Untested):

```
public static class DataHelpers
{
    // simple cache 
    private static Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>> _cache = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>>();
    
    // get columns mapping from cache or create if not exists
    private static Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> GetColumnMapping<T>()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        
        if(_cache.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            return _cache[type];
        }
        else
        {
            
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();
            
            foreach(var property in type.GetProperties())
            {
                var name = property.GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>()?.Name ?? property.Name;
                dictionary.Add(name, property);     
            }
            
            _cache.Add(type, dictionary);
            
            return dictionary;
        }
    }
      
    private static List<T> RunQuery<T>(MyDbContext context, string query,params SqlParameter[] parameters) where T : class, new()
    {
        try
        {
            using var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
            
            var oldState = connection.State;
                        
            using var command = connection.CreateCommand(); 
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            
            if(parameters?.Length > 0)
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            
            if (connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed)) 
                connection.Open();

            var mapping  = GetColumnMapping<T>();
            
            var entries = new List<T>();
                        
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {           
                if(reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var entry = new T();

                        for(int x = 0; x < reader.FieldCount; x++)
                        {
                            var columnName = reader.GetName(x);
                            
                            if(mapping.ContainsKey(columnName))
                            {
                                var property = mapping[columnName];
                                
                                var value = reader.GetValue(x);

                                if(value != null)
                                {
                                    property.SetValue(entry, Convert.ChangeType(value , property.PropertyType));
                                }                               
                            }
                        }

                        entries.Add(entry);
                    }                   
                }
            }   

            if (oldState.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed) && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
                connection.Close();
            
            return entries; // if no rows, then empty list.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"RunQuery inner: {e.InnerException}, ex:{e} \r\n {query}");
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

    }


    public static List<T> RawSqlQuery<T>(string query, , params SqlParameter[] parameters) where T : class, new()
    {
        try
        {
            using var context = MakeDbContext();
            return RunQuery<T>(context, query, parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Now your `GetNumOrderedNumDone(int jobTaskId)` would be like :

```
public static DtoNumOrderedNumDone GetNumOrderedNumDone(int jobTaskId)
{
    var sql =
        @$"select  convert(int,numordered) as Quantity , convert(int,sum(isnull(numDone,0)))  as NumDone
            from task k left outer join taskdone d on k.jobtaskid = d.jobtaskid 
            inner join job j on k.jobid = j.jobid 
            where k.jobtaskid = {jobTaskId}
            group by k.jobtaskid, j.NumOrdered";

    return DataHelpers.RawSqlQuery<DtoNumOrderedNumDone>(sql).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This would map the results to the model without the need to sepecify the mapping manually. if you need to change the property name but you still need to keep the column name as is, then apply `ColumnAttribute` on the property to read the column name from the attribute.

It might need some improvements, but at least it is enough demonstration to boost your thoughts.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to try it but I get a type error which I pasted into the bottom of my question. I worry about the performance effect of the loop through the field names inside RunQuery.  I am thinking reflection is probably ok because it is outside the loop.

Comment: @Kirsten, I've fixed the error, you can try it again. For the performance, it won't hurt much , as you're reading directly from the data-reader, which is already fast. However, the looping itself, is required for the mapping, otherwise you can use the manual mapping!

Comment: Thank you it works now.  I will wait for Peter's answer to choose.